# Standard way to pass struct to a header file

Tags: c++

I would like to know the standard/correct way to pass a `struct` declared in `main.cpp` to a class header file, where I want to alter the content of that structure in the header file. The following is a simple example of what I want to do, and it works correctly. However, I wanted to know if there is a better, more standard way to do it. I'm not too adept in C++ so I'm not sure if my current implementation has hidden flaws.

num.h

```
struct A {
    int x, y;
};

class Num {
    public:
        void change(struct A& s, int t){
            s.x = t;
        }
        int getNum(int b){
            return b;
        }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "num.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Num n;
    A a;
    a.x = 8;
    a.y = 9;

    cout << n.getNum(a.x) << endl;  \\outputs 8
    n.change(a, 5);
    cout << n.getNum(a.x) << endl;  \\outouts 5

    return 0;
}
```

Essentially, I want to have the structure `A` visible to both the `.cpp` and the `.h` file so both can alter it. Currently, my solution was to declare `struct A` at the top of the header file since the header file is like the extension of the `.cpp` file so it is as if I had declared `struct A` at the very beginning of all my code--visible to everything. I'm not sure if this is the best way though. I would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: You don't have to write `void change(struct A& s, int t)`. `void change(A& s, int t)` is more idiomatic C++.

Comment: You can just remove it from `main.cpp` and put it in the header. Then `#include` the header in `main.cpp`.

Comment: @Galik isn't that what I have done already? `struct A` is not in `.cpp` but in `.h`. I just declared an instance of it in `.cpp` so I could manipulate it. Are you suggesting that I can just declare one instance in `.h` and use it in both `.h` and `.cpp`?

Comment: @ChrisDrew Sorry but I'm not sure how that helps my situation here. I want to be able to manipulate the structure in both `.cpp` and `.h`.

Comment: Yes. Header files are the natural home of public `struct` definitions. It is how they are shared.

Comment: Define your structures and classes in `.h` files and define your implementations in `.cpp` files.

Comment: @tadman In my case, I need to be able to alter the struct within the header file. So is it ok to actually define/implement the struct in the header file as well?

Comment: @Ptheguy 'alter the struct in the header file' doesn't make much sense to me. I think you are seeing an issue which doesn't really exist, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: When you say "alter the struct" I think you mean "alter the data stored within an instance of the struct in memory" not as in "alter the nature of the struct itself" which is not valid in C++. The header defines what the struct "looks like" to the compiler. The implementation file can do whatever it wants to data stored in that format, but it can't change the format.

Comment: @john Are you suggesting that the way I have it is good?

Comment: Structs don't store data and you don't alter them. You make **objects** based on their **type** and you can make those **anywhere** you include the header file that contains the `struct` definition. It is the **objects** that you alter.

Comment: @tadman Yes that's what I mean by "alter the structure". So it's ok to implement it in the header file too right? Something like `A a` in the header file which then lets me alter the content of `a` in the header file

Comment: I think I'm good now, I get it. Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this boils down to a misunderstanding of what a header file is, and what a `struct` definition does. In your example:

```
struct A {
    int x, y;
};
```

To the compiler this reads as "there's a structure which contains two integer values, `x` and `y`, that we're going to call `A`". It doesn't allocate any memory. It doesn't run any code. It just keeps that in mind for when you talk about `A` later.

Now your `Num` code should actually be split out to separate *declaration* and *implementation*:

```
// num.h
class Num {
    public:
        void change(struct A& s, int t);
        int getNum(int b);
};
```

Where that reads to the compiler as "there's a class called `Num` that has two functions, where `change` takes a reference to an `A` struct and an integer, and `getNum` takes an integer and returns an integer". That, likewise, doesn't run any code or show up in memory, it's just a specification that's used later.

Then in something like `num.cpp` you'd spell out how that's implemented:

```
#include "num.h"

void Num::change(struct A& s, int t) {
    s.x = t;
}

int Num::getNum(int b) {
    return b;
}
```

This defines functions, executable code, that can be called by other code such as in `main()`. The `change` method reads as "using the structure definition called `A`, set the `x` integer to be the same value as the argument `t`."

This "changes the struct" inasmuch as it alters a value, but it doesn't change the structure of the `struct`. Technically you're altering the *contents* of the struct, but you're not altering the struct itself, which is why a lot of people are confused about your question.

In some languages you can change structures after they're defined, but C++ is not one of those languages.

Comment: Where's the misunderstanding? The OP's code is fine and there is no problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The code is fine, but the OPs understanding of it appears to be the problem.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. One thing that's weird with me, I like to declare and implement my functions at the same time. I'm writing code for a physics simulation so I'm deviating from this standard form. I hope that's ok!

Comment: @tadman: In what way? To me, everything they said appears to be correct.

Comment: You can declare  functions inline, but keep in mind this is not always optimal as it does have implications on how your code is compiled. C++ is a thorny subject, so having books [like these that discuss effective use of C++](https://www.aristeia.com/books.html) as a reference can help with understanding and planning.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think Tadman wanted me to separate declaration and implementation, thinking I don't see the difference. But as I said, I like to declare and implement at one go because I want to avoid having multiple .cpp files. Anyway, I appreciate Tadman's standard layout--I did ask for a standard way to code this and his is correct.

Comment: @Ptheguy: That is purely a matter of style and personal preference. There is no "standard" way. Plenty of header-only libraries exist, including most of Boost. Please take words like "should" with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is absolutely correct.

It is conventional to define types (including classes — be they introduced with `class` or `struct`) in a header file, and this is exactly why.

Well done!